# How to fix Simultaneous accesses to '', but modification requires exclusive access in Swift Graph

Tags: swift

I'm trying to create a graph in Swift, but I get the following error, when I try to run a containsCycle() methods against it: Simultaneous accesses to 0x6000034cd220, but modification requires exclusive access. Forgive me, but I don't understand the other similar (but not the same) questions, so I've asked a more specific one. Thanks for the help!

```
class Node: Hashable {
    var val: String
    var neighbors = Set<Node>()

    init(val: String) {
        self.val = val
    }

    func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
        hasher.combine(val)
        hasher.combine(neighbors)
    }

    static func == (lhs: Node, rhs: Node) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }
}

let a = Node(val: "a")
let b = Node(val: "b")
let c = Node(val: "c")
let d = Node(val: "d")
let e = Node(val: "e")
let f = Node(val: "f")
let g = Node(val: "g")
let h = Node(val: "h")
let i = Node(val: "i")
let j = Node(val: "j")
let k = Node(val: "k")

a.neighbors.insert(b)
a.neighbors.insert(c)
a.neighbors.insert(d)
a.neighbors.insert(e)

d.neighbors.insert(d) // <-- crashes here
d.neighbors.insert(a) // <-- or here, if I comment out the line above

c.neighbors.insert(g)
c.neighbors.insert(h)
c.neighbors.insert(a)

g.neighbors.insert(h)
g.neighbors.insert(c)

h.neighbors.insert(g)
h.neighbors.insert(c)

b.neighbors.insert(a)

e.neighbors.insert(a)
e.neighbors.insert(i)
e.neighbors.insert(j)
e.neighbors.insert(k)

i.neighbors.insert(e)

j.neighbors.insert(e)

k.neighbors.insert(k)
```

containsCycle() for context, but my question pertains to everything above this.

```
func containsCycle(_ node: Node) -> Bool {
    var seen = Set<Node>()
    return containsCycleRec(node, parent: nil, seen: &seen)
}

func containsCycleRec(_ node: Node, parent: Node?, seen: inout Set<Node>) -> Bool {
    seen.insert(node)
    for neighbor in node.neighbors {
        if !seen.contains(neighbor) {
            containsCycleRec(neighbor, parent: node, seen: &seen)
        } else if neighbor != parent {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: You say "I get the following error, when I try to run a containsCycle() methods against it”. But you also say `d.neighbors.insert(d) // <-- crashes here`. Which one is the issue you are asking about? Please show working code with just _one_ issue for us to understand, and mark clearly where and what _that_ issue is. Thanks.

Comment: Also: You say you don’t understand the other answers to this same issue. But you are doing _exactly_ the thing that would cause the issue: you are passing a struct (Set) as `inout` and modifying it (`seen.insert`). So it seems to me that, to that extent, this _is_ a duplicate. (I could be wrong about this, but without actually running and testing your code, that is the obvious flaw that leaps to the eye.)

Comment: I think you've answered the question in your second statement. If I understand you correctly, since a set is a struct, and not a reference type, it cannot be modified via inout (since it's a copy), and that's where the error is coming from. Seems like a shame to give up O(1) lookups and inserts by using another data structure. If Set were a class, what I'm doing would work, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: It _can_ be modified by `inout`, that’s the problem (I’m suggesting).

Answer (score 1):

Given 2 nodes that contain each other as neighbors, it creates a sort of infinite loop that (in my understanding) the compiler doesn't know where the reference loop between them ends. So, they're each attempting to modify the other simultaneously.

```
a.neighbors.contains(d) // returns true
d.neighbors.contains(a) // returns true
```

Since this was a graph problem, a nice solution ended up being to just represent the graph as an adjacency list, instead of a series of nodes that reference each other.

```
let adjList = [
    "a": ["d"],
    "d": ["a"]
]
```

I could be wrong (and I'm happy to learn something new), but this was my understanding of the problem and a solution.